# Curve Some Edges in GraphViz

Tags: graphviz

I want to draw a Chimera-type graph in GraphViz:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/jfp/resource/BLOGS_UPLOADED_IMAGES/chimera.png

So there are some straight edges, but also curved edges between particular nodes, and the nodes are fixed. I have identified all the nodes between which I want to have curved edges, but I can't get those edges to curve properly.

```
graph G {
size = 5
0 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="1,4!"]; 1 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="2,4!"]; 2 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="3,4!"]; 3 [shap\
e = circle, pin=true, pos="4,4!"]; 4 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="1,3!"]; 5 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="2,3!"]; 6 [shape = cir\
cle, pin=true, pos="3,3!"]; 7 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="4,3!"]; 8 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="1,2!"]; 9 [shape = circle, pi\
n=true, pos="2,2!"]; 10 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="3,2!"]; 11 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="4,2!"]; 12 [shape = circle, pin=tr\
ue, pos="1,1!"]; 13 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="2,1!"]; 14 [shape = circle, pin=true, pos="3,1!"]; 15 [shape = circle, pin=true, \
pos="4,1!"];
0--1; 0--5; 0--9; 0--13; 1--3 [splines = "curved"]; 2--3; 2--7; 2--11; 2--15; 4--1; 4--5; 4--9; 4--13; 5--7 [splines = "curved"]; 6--3; 6\
--7; 6--11; 6--15; 8--1; 8--5; 8--9; 8--13; 9--11 [splines = "curved"]; 10--3; 10--7; 10--11; 10--15; 12--1; 12--5; 12--9; 12--13; 13--\
15 [splines = "curved"]; 14--3; 14--7; 14--11; 14--15;
}
```

Above is my dot file. (I draw it using "neato -Tps graph.dot -o graph.ps").

I think you can globally curve edges by putting splines = "curved" as a graph property, but I want to individually curve certain edges, or at least not have all the crazy overlapping I currently have.

Comment: Just tried splines = "curved" globally and it worked, but I think that was partly luck that not every edge became curved (the straight edges in the Chimera graph are quite short - maybe if they were longer they wouldn't stay straight). My question of how to keep certain edges straight while other edges curved in the general case still stands.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I changed your code to

```
graph G {
  size = 5
  node [shape = circle, pin=true ]

   0 [ pos="1,4!" ]; 
   1 [ pos="2,4!" ]; 
   2 [ pos="3,4!" ]; 
   3 [ pos="4,4!"]; 
   4 [ pos="1,3!"]; 
   5 [ pos="2,3!"]; 
   6 [ pos="3,3!"]; 
   7 [ pos="4,3!"]; 
   8 [ pos="1,2!"]; 
   9 [ pos="2,2!"]; 
  10 [ pos="3,2!"]; 
  11 [ pos="4,2!"]; 
  12 [ pos="1,1!"]; 
  13 [ pos="2,1!"]; 
  14 [ pos="3,1!"]; 
  15 [ pos="4,1!"];

  0 -- { 1, 5, 9, 13 }
  1 -- 3 ; 
  2 -- { 3, 7, 11 15 }
  4 -- {1, 5, 9, 13 } 
  5 -- 7;
  6 -- { 3, 7, 11, 15 }
  8 -- { 1, 5, 9, 13 } 
  9 -- 11; 
  10 -- { 3, 7, 11, 15 } 
  12 -- { 1, 5, 9, 13 }
  13 -- 15; 
  14 -- { 3, 7, 11, 15 }
}
```

and compiled with

```
neato -Tpng -Gsplines=true so.gv -o so.png
```

and got

[image]

Is that closer to what you want?